# Azure Batch services scheduling options

Tags: azure, job-scheduling, azure-batch

I am having hard time in deciding the right Job Scheduling for Azure Batch Services.

Does anyone have a thought to share on what could be used ?

I came up with only 2 options:

1. JobSchedule Class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt460022.aspx)
2. Azure Batch Scheduling

Answer (score 0):

Azure Batch is a job scheduling service with its own API/SDK. The JobSchedule Class you reference is not part of the Azure Batch API (it appears to be Azure Automation).

For more information about how Azure Batch works, please see [this technical overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-technical-overview/). There are a variety of SDKs available including .NET, Java, and Python in addition to a REST API along with [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples).